# Information about support for Focusrite 2i2

Tags: sound, audio-recording

I have 2 audio interfaces, a Focusrite 2i2 and a Behringer UMC404HD. Until recently, both were recognized and somewhat useful, but I could not figure out how to separate the input channels on either. I recently installed Ubuntu Desktop 23.10 Mantic Minotaur in a separate partition, and the Focusrite 2i2 channels were recognized! I also installed Ubuntu Studio 23.10, and the channels were not recognized. I don't know if this is supported in the 6.5 kernel or what. Where can I find out more about the project(s) that are providing this awesome support?